# Pass Anonymous function that requires a parameter, to another function as an argument which will be assigned to an onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function that I want to reuse throughout my program. Basically it's a bootstrap dialog box that has a confirm and a cancel button. I setup the helper function to accept two anonymous functions, one for the cancel and one for the confirm. I have everything working except I am not sure how to properly assign it to the onclick when building the html. I want to avoid using a global variable but this is the only way I was able to get this to work.

Custom function:

```
    function confirmMessageBox(msg, cancelFunc, confirmFunc) {
    var html = ' <div class="container"><div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmMsgModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation Needed</h4></div><div class="locationTableCanvas"><div class="modal-body"><p>' + msg + '</p></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><table><tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick = "(' + cancelFunc + ')()">Cancel</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick = "(' + confirmFunc + ')()">Confirm</button></td></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div>';
    $("#confirmMsgContainer").html(html);
    $('#ConfirmMsgModal').modal('show');
}
```

I have to do, onclick = "(' + cancelFunc + ')()"> because if I do, onclick = "' + cancelFunc() + '">   it shows up as undefined.  The current way will basically just print the anonymous function out and assign it to the onclick (almost as if I just typed out the anonymous function right at the onclick)

here is where I call the function:

```
    var transTypeHolder;
$("input[name='transType']").click(function () {
    var tabLength = $('#SNToAddList  tbody  tr').length;
    if (tabLength == 0) {
        var selection = $(this).attr("id");
        serialAllowableCheck(selection);
        resetSerialNumberCanvasAndHide();
        $("#Location").val("");
        $("#SerialNumber").val("");
    }
    else {
        transTypeHolder = $(this).val();
        var confirm = function () {

            var $radios = $('input:radio[name=transType]');
            $radios.filter('[value='+transTypeHolder+']').prop('checked', true);
            resetSerialNumberCanvasAndHide();
            $('#Location').val('');
            $('#SerialNumber').val('');
        };
        var cancel = function () {};
        confirmMessageBox("This is a test", cancel, confirm);
        return false;
    }

});
```

Is there a way to some how pass a variable to the anonymous function without using the global variable I have as, "transTypeHolder"  ?

Before I get the, "Why are you doing it this way??" response; Javascript isn't a strong language of mine, as I am using ASP.NET MVC4. I haven't had a chance to sit down and learn Javascript in detail and I sort of picked it up and search what I need. So if there is a better way of tackling this, I am open for constructive criticism.

Comment: Use jQuery to attach the event handlers, just like you are with the `input[name='transType']`, just with a different selector (maybe give the confirm button a class like, say, "confirm"; then you can target it with `.confirm`). It's a little unclear where else you're using `transTypeHolder` besides in the click handler, so why would you need it to be global?

Comment: Because when I attempt to assign it to the onclick inside the html of, $("#confirmMsgContainer").html(html);  It is looking for that variable directly, and not its value. So I am sure there is a better way of approaching this but this was what I could get to work. I couldn't really find a good to build the html with the onclick assigned to the anonymous function inside the confirmMessageBox function

Comment: No, I'm saying, don't use `onclick` in the HTML at all. Assign it like `$('.confirm').on('click', function () { ... });` after you open the message box.

Comment: ah okay, yea maybe I can play around with it like that too. I just did it this way because it's easier to use for other developers too. All you would have to know about the dialog is to call that function, and pass the message string, as well as the functions (anonymous or not) on how to handle the confirm or cancel.

Comment: I've added an answer which solves some of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make event handler assignments in HTML at all. If you want people to be able to supply their own functions for canceling and confirming use `on`:

```
function confirmMessageBox(msg, cancelFunc, confirmFunc) {
    var html = ' <div class="container"><div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmMsgModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation Needed</h4></div><div class="locationTableCanvas"><div class="modal-body"><p>' + msg + '</p></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><table><tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirm" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button></td></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div>';
    $("#confirmMsgContainer").html(html);
    $("#confirmMsgContainer").off('click', '.confirm').on('click', '.confirm', confirmFunc);
    $("#confirmMsgContainer").off('click', '.cancel').on('click', '.cancel', cancelFunc);
    $('#ConfirmMsgModal').modal('show');
}
```

Note that I've edited the HTML you're using to remove the `onclick`s and added a class to each button. I'm also using `off` to be sure any previously added event handlers are removed.

As far as passing the variable to the confirm function without using a global, use a closure:

```
var transTypeHolder = $(this).val();
var confirm = (function (typeHolder) { 
    return function () {
        var $radios = $('input:radio[name=transType]');
        $radios.filter('[value='+typeHolder+']').prop('checked', true);
        resetSerialNumberCanvasAndHide();
        $('#Location').val('');
        $('#SerialNumber').val('');
    };
})(transTypeHolder);
```

That tells JavaScript to create a function, which returns a function that does what you want it to do. That "function creator" takes in the variable you want to keep around, allowing it to be used elsewhere.

Now, I haven't tested this, so you may have some debugging in your future, but hopefully it gives you a jumping-off point.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That looks like the answer I am looking for. I am having a hell of a time getting the anonymous function inside the closure  to work though. I have been trying for about an hour, but for whatever reason the function won't call. I don't see any console errors in the debugger, and I threw an alert in there just to see if it's getting called and for some reason it's not. I will keep working with it though for a little while longer. I also tried setting the function inside the html, originally (w/out jquery) the way I had it, but for some reason it doesn't like the closure

Comment: Hmm, hard to say. If you have a more complete version on jsfiddle.net or something like that I might be able to take a look. It's a bit hard to recreate the same circumstances without the HTML.

Comment: Right, understandable. Let me see if I can whip something on in JsFiddle, might help me too.

Comment: JSFiddle was even more work trying to figure out lol. So I went back to my code and messed around with it some more. I changed, the $("..").off().on to $('#confirmDlgConfirmBtn').click(confirmFunc);  and then it finally worked. Not sure why .off().on() handlers were giving me issues. But this works for me, and The closure method is GREAT! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by having the function being acessible from global context under a generated name (which can be multiple if you have more than one instance of the box), like so:

```
function confirmMessageBox(msg, cancelFunc, confirmFunc) {
    window['generatedCancelFunctionName1'] = cancelFunc;
    window['generatedConfirmFunctionName1'] = confirmFunc;
    var html = ' <div class="container"><div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmMsgModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation Needed</h4></div><div class="locationTableCanvas"><div class="modal-body"><p>' + msg + '</p></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><table><tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick = "generatedCancelFunctionName1()">Cancel</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick = "generatedConfirmFunctionName1()">Confirm</button></td></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div>';
    $("#confirmMsgContainer").html(html);
    $('#ConfirmMsgModal').modal('show');
}
```

This way you are not obliged to expose the function code. You can also set an id attribute to the element and set a jquery click() function like in the second part (but you would need the html to be created before you set the click)

Comment: That's just making more global variables, which he's already said he doesn't want to do. Just because you decorate it with `window['name']` doesn't make it not a global...

Comment: well my answer seems rather clear if you read until the end, i clearly say the first part is global, and explains that he needs an id and setting the click with jquery to avoid being global..