# How to control related text input element with a button?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of text-field + button that gets rendered dynamically. The user hits the button and I want to control the input field when a button is clicked.

I figure you could do something like:

```html
    <input id="1"><button onclick="doSomething(1)">Something</button>
    <input id="2"><button onclick="doSomething(2)">Something</button>
    <!--...-->
    <input id="3"><button onclick="doSomething(3)">Something</button>
```

But wonder if there's a different and more sophisticated solution because the code I'm modifying passes an an anonymous function to onclick and I can't pass a unique ID like the method above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Anonymous function that requires a parameter, to another function as an argument which will be assigned to an onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576865/pass-anonymous-function-that-requires-a-parameter-to-another-function-as-an-arg)

Comment: It would be very easy if each input and button were in divs and u could use this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(‘input’)[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve in vanilla Javascript (as most things). No jQuery overhead required here.

```js
let buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName('inputbutton')]

function doSomething(i) {
  console.log(i);
}

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const i = e.target.previousSibling.id
    doSomething(i);
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="1"><button class="inputbutton" type="button">Something</button>
<input id="2"><button  class="inputbutton" type="button">Something</button>
<!--...-->
<input id="3"><button  class="inputbutton" type="button">Something</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your dynamic HTML like the following and add this jQuery, you will be able to access the value of the previous input field.

```js
var buttons = $(".inputs-and-buttons #button-after-input-field");
buttons.click(function() {
  console.log($(this).prev("input").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs-and-buttons">
  <input id="1" value="1"><button id="button-after-input-field">Something</button>
  <input id="2" value="2"><button id="button-after-input-field">Something</button>
  <!--...-->
  <input id="3" value="3"><button id="button-after-input-field">Something</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic Id for both input field and button with index or row number or you can add custom attribute for row number as below.

You can generate dynamic related control with specific Id for textbox and button as well. e.g. txtFirstName_1, txtLastName_1, btnAdd_1. here textbox and button distinguished by its id and number after Underscore **"_"** .

```js
$(function(){
// Register click on button
//here you can pass specific class name for button if all are have same functionality
$("button").click(function(e){
console.log(this);
var btnId=$(this).attr("id");
//console.log(btnId);
// Way 1
//Split btnId with "_"  e.g btn_1 will splited with ["btn","1"]
var rowIndex=btnId.split("_")[1];
console.log(btnId.split("_"),rowIndex);
$("#txt_"+rowIndex).val("Upate value by btn"+rowIndex); // Or fetch value

// Way 2 
// You can directly use custom attribute data-row and do your work
var rowIndex1=$(this).attr("data-row");//$(e).prop("data-row");
console.log(rowIndex1);
//$("#txt_"+rowIndex1).val("Upate value"); // Or fetch value
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt_1" data-row="1"><button  id="btn_1" data-row="1">Something</button>
<input id="txt_2" data-row="2"><button  id="btn_2" data-row="2">Something</button>
<input id="txt_3" data-row="3"> <button  id="btn_3" data-row="3">Something</button>
```